# Javascript or JQuery need page reload, Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, real-time

Why does Javascript or jQuery need a page reload before it applies certain effects?

CSS is updates in real-time

Example:

This works in real time

```
@media all and (max-width:767px) {
.nav-menu {
 margin:0px!important;
 }
 }
```

This needs a page reload to see the effect, don't update on resize window in real time

```
if ($(window).width() > 980) {
do something
};
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that latter is JavaScript. Currently it's a routine that is fired only once on when the script tag is parsed. You can wrap it in a function and fire it multiple times. For example on a window resize event. The former is CSS and browsers continually update the page according to the CSS rules.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
     if ($(window).width() > 980) {
         do something
     };
}, false);
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
     if ($(window).width() > 980) {
         do something
     };
});
```

Now this will fire everytime the window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the jQuery/Javascript thing is done on load and not when you resize the window. The CSS is, in theory, also done on load and just knows what to display when.

If you want to run the JS/jQuery when you resize the window, you have to add something like this:

```
window.onresize = resize;

function resize()
{
  if ($(window).width() > 980) {
     //do something
  };
}
```

The above piece of code will run every time you resize the window and therefore check every time it runs if the window is wider than 980.

[Read more about `.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)

Comment: You also came up with the same answer. Personally I prefer to advise people to use `addEventListener`. Overwriting `window.onresize` can cause problems with (badly written) libraries/ third party scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This will work when the `resize` event is fired

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() > 980) {
       ... 
        .....
        ....
    }
 });
```

This will work

> ref - **[resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)** function in jquery

Comment: JavaScript is real-time. This works when the resize event is fired ;-)

Comment: yes it will work let me update the answer with proper message thanks @Mouser

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger an event to make the javascript check for that condition without loading the page

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // add your if condition here
};
```

for jquery simply use the below

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // add you if condition here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).width()
```

When you call a function like this gives you a return value when it is execute. If you want to give a value when resize, document click etc. you have to add a event listener.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {

    console.log( $(window).width() )

});
```